# CREATE statement fails in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, sql, asp.net-mvc, crud

My create statement could not work suddenly and it goes straight to an error message (Account cannot be created). I am not sure where I went wrong as I did not make any modification to it at all. In total, I have encountered this problem THRICE and my only solution is to make a new project for it to work again with the same exact codes. Any suggestions to ensure no such thing happen again in the future? Thank you in advance! Here are my codes in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateUser(Users usr)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Invalid Input";
        ViewData["MsgType"] = "warning";
        return View("CreateUser");
    }
    else
    {
        string insert = @"INSERT INTO WBUsers(UserId, UserPw,FullName, Email, UserRole, Dob, ContactNo, usr.Billing_Address)
                          VALUES('{0}', HASHBYTES('SHA1', '{1}'), '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', {6}, '{7}')";

        if (DBUtl.ExecSQL(insert, usr.UserId, usr.UserPw, usr.FullName, usr.Email, usr.UserRole, usr.Dob, usr.ContactNo, usr.Billing_Address) == 1)
        {
            string template = @"Hi {0},<br/><br/>
                          Welcome to WorldBay!
                           Your userid is <b>{1}</b> and password is <b>{2}</b>. Please change your password upon login.
                           <br/><br/>Adminstrator";
            string title = "Account Sign Up";
            string message = String.Format(template, usr.FullName, usr.UserId, usr.UserPw);
            string result = "";

            bool outcome = false;
                
            outcome = EmailUtl.SendEmail(usr.Email, title, message, out result);

            if (outcome)
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "Account has been created";
                ViewData["MsgType"] = "success";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = result;
                ViewData["MsgType"] = "warning";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Account cannot be created";
            ViewData["MsgType"] = "danger";
        }

        return View("CreateUser");
    }
}
```

DBUtil code consists of:

```
public static int ExecSQL(string sql, params object[] list)
{
    List<String> escParams = new List<String>();

    foreach (object o in list)
    {
        if (o == null)
            escParams.Add("");
        else
            escParams.Add(EscQuote(o.ToString()));
    }

    DB_SQL = String.Format(sql, escParams.ToArray());

    int rowsAffected = 0;

    using (SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(DB_CONNECTION))
    using (SqlCommand dbCmd = dbConn.CreateCommand())
    {
         try
         {
              dbConn.Open();
              dbCmd.CommandText = DB_SQL;
              rowsAffected = dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         catch (System.Exception ex)
         {
              DB_Message = ex.Message;
              rowsAffected = -1;
         }
     }

     return rowsAffected;
}
```

Comment: What was the errror? On which line? Stacktrace?

Comment: it goes straight to ViewData["Message"] = "Account Cannot Be Created";
                ViewData["MsgType"] = "danger";    @Charlieface

Comment: What is the code for `DBUtl.ExecSQL` and why does it not just throw an exception? Is it your code?

Comment: @Charlieface I have included the codes for DBUtl.ExecSQL in the above section. It would usually throw an exception if there was an error in the sql statement.

Comment: Start by removing the `try/catch` in `ExecSQL`, then you can see what the exception is. Incidentally, I don't know where you got this code, but it should be using `SqlParameter`

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Since your code in _DBUtil_ swallows the exception, no one can guess why it failed. You need to check what is there in that _DB_message_ variable or bubble up the exception and  log the message on the console.

Comment: if thats the case may I know whats the best code to use other than the one above? I am new to asp.net mvc

Comment: Change the line `ViewData["Message"] = "Account cannot be created";` with `ViewData["Message"] = DB_message;` and post here the exact message that you are seeing.

Comment: @Thangadurai now it freezes when I click the submit button. It does not display any error message